# "Молния"

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, слово "молния" в значении "застежка" берется в кавычки или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, кавычки не нужны. **МОЛНИЯ** в смысле "застежка" - общеизвестное значение, зафиксированное в словарях: "Застёжка для одежды, обуви и т.п., имеющая вид ленты с зубчиками и скользящим вдоль неё замком". Например: *Вставить, вшить, задёрнуть, расстегнуть молнию. Куртка с молнией, на молнии. Разъёмная молния. Пластмассовая, металлическая молния*.